# How to execute a command in a bash script and then focus the appearing window

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, focus, window

I have a bash script like this

```
#!/bin/sh
firefox &
```

The Firefox window opens, but it doesn't have focus. What can I do so that it has the focus automatically?

I could use some X window tools / commands, but how do I get the window ID of Firefox? The window name is changing with the URLs displayed and therefore not useful.

EDIT: My window manager is Gnome.

Comment: This totally depends on your window manager. Name it (or your desktop environment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool) is the tool to do so.

The simplest form for your particular task is

```
xdotool  windowactivate `xdotool search --pid $! `
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about this $! parameter yet. My version of xdotool obviously doesn't support the --pid parameter, but I've seen it in online man pages so probably I just need to upgrade.