# OSX bash - window focusing on launched executables/apps?

Tags: macos, bash, focus, window

If i launch a executable/another app from a bash script, this executable/app starts up normally, but with it's application window not in focus.
If you launch the script from a window for example, the bash script calls upon the other executable/app, but you can't see the app's interface because it gets launched below all windows.

For Linux there exist some window managers that can do this, like these [tips](https://superuser.com/questions/142945/bash-command-to-focus-a-specific-window) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226636/how-to-execute-a-command-in-a-bash-script-and-then-focus-the-appearing-window):

Is there something for OSX as well?

I realize i can set the active window via AppleScript (osascript via bash), but i wanted to do this without AS.

> ("tell application \"newapp\" to
>   activate")

Comment: Are you using "open myApplication.app"?  perhaps post some of your current script?

Comment: window fucus is lost on both "open myapplication.app" and exec pathto/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/app". osascript helps out a bit here, but it doesn't always work; especially if the script launches one app and gives it focus via osascript, then kills it and launches another app some time after that. second app never gets focus with an additional osascript 'activate' command.

Answer (score 3):

My [appswitch](http://sabi.net/nriley/software/#appswitch) tool does exactly this.